# Decoding data from RFID tag's memory contents in Android Studio

Tags: android, nfc, rfid, lib-nfc

I am developing an App to read the Barcode of our library books from there respective RFID tags. I am using `android.nfc.tech.NfcV`and able to read the memory contents of the tag, which seems to be Hexadecimal byte array.

how can I decode the BarCode and other information from the Hexadecimal bytes of RFID tag?

The screenshot shows information of one the book's RFID tag(shows the Hexadecimal byte array).([NFC tool](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wakdev.wdnfc&hl=en_IN) app is used.)

**In this example the Barcode of the book is- 226866**.

[image: System Information of RFID tag]
[image: The Memory of the tag]

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear.  using `nfcv` object from `android.nfc.tech.NfcV` I am able to read the memory content of the RFID tag as a byte array. I am looking for ways to decode the byte array and get the information stored in actual form. @iso8583.infosupport

Comment: Your hex data is 11/03/03/76/32/02/01/20/50/01/10. If you look at the bytes 3, 4 and 5 you have 03/76/32. These numbers, converted from hex to decimal are 226866, which is your expected value. May this be a hint for you?

Comment: Excellent Observation! This is indeed working. Thanks man :)

Comment: if you want you can post it as an answer